# GROUP BY the number of rows returned by GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table - for the purposes of this question, it has one column `word`. The following information is in this table:

- `apple` - appears 3 times
- `banana` - appears 5 times
- `pear` - appears 3 times

I wrote the following SQL code to select each word uniquely, along with the number of times that word appears in the table:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(word) FROM table GROUP BY word ORDER BY COUNT(word) DESC;
```

This returns me the following information:

```
--------------------------
| word     | COUNT(word) |
--------------------------
| banana   | 5           |
--------------------------
| apple    | 3           |
--------------------------
| pear     | 3           |
--------------------------
```

Is there a way to write a query to return the following information:

```
-----------------------------
| COUNT(word) | words       |
-----------------------------
| 5           | banana      |
-----------------------------
| 3           | apple, pear |
-----------------------------
```

I was thinking along the lines of double `GROUP BY`, but haven't thought of much yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT word_count, GROUP_CONCAT(word SEPARATOR ', ') as words
FROM (SELECT word, COUNT(word) as word_count
      FROM table 
      GROUP BY word) w
GROUP BY word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
```

Comment: did the trick - just do note that `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't take a comma - it needs to have `SEPARATOR`, followed by the separator in quotation marks.